# How to remove application installed using snap : cannot update snap namespace: invalid argument

Tags: mount, uninstall, snap, audacity

I am trying to remove an application from snap ... here is my initial condition

```
sudo snap install audacity   #  install


type audacity
audacity is hashed (/snap/bin/audacity)


snap list  | grep audacity
audacity            2.4.1                       675   latest/stable    diddledan        -
```

when I launch from a terminal

```
audacity
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/olga/snap/audacity/675/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini': File exists
.... more messages here
```

so it runs just fine however when I try to uninstall I get this error

```
sudo snap remove audacity 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Disconnect audacity:wayland from core:wayland (cannot update mount namespace of snap "audacity": cannot update preserved namespace of snap "audacity": cannot update snap namespace: invalid argument)
```

naturally I am tempted to force it by just removing these dirs

> /snap/bin/audacity

> /home/olga/snap/audacity

however I suspect there is a cleaner way ... sure would be gr8 if snap kept users like me on a short leash by emitting more useful error messages and/or behavior